# Creating a custom form that looks and validates like a webform

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, drupal-webform

Edit: Accidentally posted uncompleted question.

I need to have a custom form that looks and responds the same as a webforms form.

I have a drupal website which needs a cusotm form to tie into ZOHO CRM (Send leads).

I use webforms for the rest of my site however I am unable to use webforms as I need to customize the action, classes, and IDs of the form to send data to ZOHO.

I want my custom form to look and validate like the webforms forms for consistency. I am unable to implement the same validation.

I have not found a clear and simple article about this yet and it seems so basic perhaps I am over thinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out Drupal's form API:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

if you want you can hook into a webform:
http://api.lullabot.com/group/webform_hooks/7

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form API as tmsimont suggested.

Use

```
function yourmodule_form(){        
  $form['search_field'] = array(
  '#title' => t(''),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => '18',
  '#default_value' => $form_text,
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Buscar'),
);

//then to do your custom validation!
your_module_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state)
{
  if(strlen($form_state['values']['search_field'])<3)
  {
    form_set_error('search_field', t("Search term too small."));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GOOGLE  "JQuery Validate"  and look at the examples